Is Sarswati embodied in a computer?
So my school computer was in front of my feet and while sitting and watching the TV I gently rested my legs on it. My mother told me not to put my legs on Sarswati and that all knowledge systems are holy. I responded by stating bad knowledge exists and is cataloged all the time and that we sadly don't follow the dietary restrictions, so it is hypocritical for you to criticize me when you don't follow the sacred tradition. She said we Brahmins "evolved" during the times and no longer follow those restrictions. I know it was BS and in that case, no tradition should be followed also onion and garlic were not eaten for spiritual not just health reasons. But, my question is very simple. Is Saraswati somehow embodied within items that store knowledge such as Hindu scriptures, other books, and computers? Or, are only Hindu scriptures written on paper? If, so is there any penance for this possibly sinful act? Oh, note I do use my computer for religious study sometimes.
